# Use orgmode agenda content in html

Tags: html, emacs, calendar, elisp, org-mode

I am working on an agenda and orgmode works great in all of senses. Unfortunatelly I am stalled in one point: to export orgmode agenda content to HTML.

I know how to export the .org to ics and it works fine. I know how to export the .org to html and it also works. But when you export .org to HTML you miss the content of the agenda. I mean, if I have schedulled an event, it is like:

```
* Convocatoria de Proyectos Visualizar15
DEADLINE: <2015-04-05 dom>
http://medialab-prado.es/article/tallervisualizar15proyectos
```

The HTML is:

```
Convocatoria de Proyectos Visualizar15
http://medialab-prado.es/article/tallervisualizar15proyectos
```

So I miss the content of the DEADLINE. I would like not to rewrite every date and use the orgmode agenda content.

Is it possible?

Best!

Comment: Did you check `org-export-with-planning`? http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings

Comment: Obviously I didn't. So simple, so org-mode:`#+OPTIONS:  p:with-planning`